# Magento 1.9.2.4 Product Information missing tabs

Tags: php, database, attributes, magento-1.9

I made a migration from an older version of magento to a new 1.9.2.4 version, but now the product information is missing few tabs. Most important one is the Images and the Detailed Info. 
[image]

Do you have any idea of what the problem might be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out that the attributes were messed up and need to check them again in order to get additional options for the product information.